# request for member 'testLogin' in 'k', whitch is pointer type 'Konto*'

Tags: c++

Hello I am learning c++ right now but I dont find an answer to my error.

The Problem is k.testLogin(); and produces the Error: [Error] request for member 'testLogin' in 'k', which is of pointer type 'Konto*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

```
The function testLogin() from Konto looks like this and is public:
void testLogin()
        {
            (empty right now because doesnt work)
        }
```

Konstruktor of Konto:

```
Konto(char response)
    {
        switch(response)
            {   
                case ('1'): neuesKonto(); cout<<"\nKonto wurde erstellt!";break;
                case ('2'): logIn();break;
                default: cout<<"\nFalsche Eingabe!";break;
            }
    }
```

this is my main:

```
Konto* k;
bool loggedIn;
int main() {
    srand(0);
    do
    {
        cout <<"Bankkonten verwalten und erstellen...\n";
    cout <<"--- 1 = neuesKonto --- 2 = LOG-IN --- \n";  
    cout <<"Eingabe: "; 
    char response;
    std::cin >> response;
    k = new Konto(response);
    k.testLogin();

    }while(loggedIn == true);

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works I only cant run k.testLogin(); ...

Thank you for help... Konto.h is kinda big so I dont post it here if not needed.

Comment: did you read the error message?

Comment: Can anybody translate the error message "maybe you meant to use '->' ?". Could this maybe??? a hint to the problem? :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about reading your own error message?

> maybe you meant to use '->' ?

`k->testLogin()` would be the correct way in your case.

Comment: Maybe it was upvoted while the user has 2 accounts ;) But simply: It is the correct answer and so it is really ok to do this ;) But I also don't know who did this :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer I did not know this even exists in c++ I come from Java ;)

Comment: @spyce In this case, reconsider if you really need a pointer. Most of the times you do not, and owning raw pointers are never good C++. For more information get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).