# How can I make my program accept pointers?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make my program accept pointers as part of a requirement to deallocate the heap space and kill the pointer. My program runs fine without the adjustments I attempted to make to accept pointers. I'm getting the following error

```
lab.cpp: In function 'int main()':
lab.cpp:21:19: error: request for member 'unit' in 'shipment', which is of pointer type 'cargo*'
(maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
21 |    input(shipment.unit);
  |                   ^~~~
lab.cpp:22:20: error: request for member 'unit' in 'shipment', which is of pointer type 'cargo*'   
(maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
22 |    output(shipment.unit);
  |                    ^~~~
```

Here is my program without the adjustments, really simple but it works. All it's doing is taking input and outputting it, just setting it up for now as my assignment is to collect data from user and output it while deallocating the heapspace

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct cargo{
   string unit;
   string unitID;
   int airCraft;
   int weight;
   string destination;
};
void input(cargo shipment){
   cout << "Is it a pallet or a container?" << endl; 
   getline(cin, shipment.unit);
}
void output(cargo shipment){
   cout << shipment.unit << endl;
}

int main() {
   cargo shipment;
   input(shipment);
   output(shipment);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my program with my adjustments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct cargo{
   string unit;
   string unitID;
   int airCraft;
    int weight;
    string destination;
 };
 void input(cargo *shipment){
    cout << "Is it a pallet or a container?" << endl; 
    getline(cin, shipment.unit);
 }
 void output(cargo *shipment){
    cout << shipment.unit << endl;
 }

 int main() {
    cargo *shipment = new cargo;
    input(shipment.unit);
    output(shipment.unit);
    delete shipment;
    shipment = nullptr;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The error message tells you how to fix the error.

Comment: as @JaMiT Told compiler already showed you what is wrong. First version you passing arguments by coping objects in second you what to pass pointer but you didn't passing it correctly. Just pass &shipment instead of shipment.unit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [request for member 'testLogin' in 'k', whitch is pointer type 'Konto\*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729332/request-for-member-testlogin-in-k-whitch-is-pointer-type-konto)

Comment: Tip: There's really no reason to set to `nullptr` here. `delete` is sufficient. There are cases where you want to track your deletions but that's not relevant in this context.

Comment: In case you are unfamiliar with how compilers report errors: look at the character sequence `^~~~` in the error message. That is an arrow pointing to a specific character (in this case, a period). That period is the subject of the error "request for member". The suggested fix is that maybe instead of `.` you meant to (and should) use `->`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing an pointer's members, you need to use the arrow (`->`) operator. But your methods `input` and `output` takes the `cargo` pointer. After accessing its member, you'll return the member, not the pointer. So by doing `shipment.unit`, your returning a string.

To fix it, lest just pass in the pointer.

```cpp
void input(cargo *shipment){
    cout << "Is it a pallet or a container?" << endl; 
    getline(cin, shipment->unit);
 }
 void output(cargo *shipment){
    cout << shipment->unit << endl;
}

...

input(shipment);
output(shipment);
```

Additional: After deleting the `shipment`, assigning it a `nullptr` is useless. Your not gonna use it anyway.